# Scrape data-view value from website using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm ok at configuring /altering PHP, but not proficient enough to write it from scratch - was wondering if someone can help me with this please?

Basically I wish to scrape a small amount of data from the website, which is in the format:

```
<div class="PDPVariantOption" data-value="XYZ" data-variant="ClothingSize">
```

and I wish to extract just the XYZ bit

```
$html->load($result["body"]);

    $rows = $html->find("div.PDPVariantOption");
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "\t" . $row . "\n";
    }
```

This is the code I'm using (in conjunction with http://barebonescms.com/documentation/ultimate_web_scraper_toolkit/ ) but this extracts everything which is within the div tag - I've tried various options using getAttribute and similar to get the "data-value" value (pure guesswork from me I'm afraid!) but no luck - can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance

Joey

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK this is my complete code which works:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = '<div class="PDPVariantOption" data-value="XYZ" data-variant="ClothingSize">
<div class="PDPVariantOption" data-value="BHB" data-variant="ClothingSize">
<div class="differentName">
<div class="PDPVariantOption" data-value="567" data-variant="ClothingSize">
<div class="PDPVariantOption" data-value="123" data-variant="ClothingSize">
<div class="PDPVariantOption" data-value="rty" data-variant="ClothingSize">';

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$result = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'PDPVariantOption')]");

for ($i; $i < $result->length; $i++) {
    $row = $result->item($i)->getAttribute('data-value');
    echo $row . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I'm really sorry but I couldn't get this to work - my code is now:

    $html->load($result["body"]);

    $rows = $html->find('div[data-value]')->{'data-value'};
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "\t" . $row . "\n";
    }

But it won't output anything? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok Check my edited answer. This is my demo script which works for me using getAttribute which is simpler.

Comment: Thanks so much Ben, I really appreciate it - I've got it working - and sorry to be such a pain, but is there anyway of restricting this to just divs with the class PDPVariantOption - as there are other divs on the page which this is returning blank lines for (presumably as they're divs without a data-value)

Comment: Ah yeah ok my bad. I have now fixed my answer to only get divs with a set classname, I totally forgot about that.

Comment: Thank you so much Ben - spent all day yesterday trying to fix this, really appreciate your help :) Have a great day!

Comment: No problem man. Shame I've been downvoted by someone though, wish they would comment why!